# Error Android Studio: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0. Information:BUILD FAILED

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle

Estoy trabajando con Android Studio 2.1 y Ubunto 16 LTS. He instalado Java correctamente. No hay manera en que pueda compilar ningún proyecto ya que cada vez que lo hago recibo el siguiente error:

> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0. Information:BUILD FAILED

Ya he ingresado las variables de entorno, reinstalando Android Studio y nada.

Aquí está el log completo:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:clean
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2410Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72410Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42410Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2410Library
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   :app:compileDebugShaders
>   :app:generateDebugAssets
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>   :app:processDebugManifest
>   :app:processDebugResources
>   :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
>   :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 4.617 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Hola @JuankGlezz Gracias por responder. No me di cuenta, me debe haber redireccionado el foro en inglés. Acabo de probar nuevamente una solución que intenté hace más de una semana y funcionó. De igual manera reformulo la pregunta para otros usuarios en el foro o la debo eliminar?.

Comment: Listo! Lo he solucionado eliminando el contenido de la carpeta ~.gradle/caches/2.10. Todo corre perfectamente.

Comment: @JuankGlezz Maravilloso muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado eliminando el contenido de la carpeta ~.gradle/caches/2.10.

Comment: DISCULPA TENGO EL MISMO PROBLEMA QUE CARPETA , ES PARA ELIMINAR

Comment: @DalilaRodasVargas Hay que vaciar la caché de Gradle. Depende de la versión que uses. Prueba eliminando todo lo que esté dentro de la carpeta .gradle y luego reinicia Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que este problema esta relacionado a algún tipo de corrupción en el folder `.gradle` del proyecto.

Por lo tanto la solución es borrar el contenido del folder `.gradle/` y reiniciar Android Studio.

Para encontrar la ubicación del directorio `.gradle/`, podemos ir a la configuración del proyecto, `settings` o `preferences` en MAC entrar a `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]